# Convert a string of ids into a string of equivalent names

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table (mock data) :

| ID | Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Main | / |
| 2 | Photos | /1/3 |
| 3 | Media | /1 |
| 4 | Charts | / |
| 5 | Expenses | /4 |

The column `Location` is a string with ids that refer to that very table.
I'm looking for a query to convert ids into names, something like this :

| ID | Name | Location | FullName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Main | / | / |
| 2 | Photos | /1/3 | /Main/Media |
| 3 | Media | /1 | /Main |
| 4 | Charts | / | / |
| 5 | Expenses | /4 | /Charts |

This is some mock data, in my real table I have more complex locations.
I'm not the owner of the table so I can't modify the schema. I can only read it.
Someone has an idea ?
Thank you very much

I've been exploring with this function : `regexp_split_to_table`

```sql
WITH flat_data AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        col.id col_id, 
        col.name col_name,
        col.location col_full_loc,
        regexp_split_to_table(col.location, '/') as loc_item
    FROM collection col),
clean_data AS (
    SELECT
        col_id,
        col_name,
        col_full_loc,
        CASE WHEN loc_item = '' THEN null ELSE loc_item::integer END loc_item,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by col_id, loc_item)
    FROM flat_data
) select * from clean_data
```

So I've managed to have something like this :
| ID | Name | Location | AfterFunction |
| -- | -- | -- | -- |
| 1 | Main | / |   |
| 2 | Photos | /1/3 |   |
| 2 | Photos | /1/3 | 3 |
| 2 | Photos | /1/3 |   |
| 2 | Photos | /1/3 | 1 |
| 3 | Media | /1 |   |
| 3 | Media | /1 | 1 |
| 4 | Charts | / |   |
| 5 | Expenses | /4 |   |
| 5 | Expenses | /4 | 4 |

But at some point I lose the order of sublocation item

EDIT : table style

Comment: Write a function that takes location as input, parse the string inside, concatenate with names from the same table, and returns it. Use the same in your query to get the last column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook to the solution

1. ignore the first slash in the `location` to simplify the split and mapping (add it again at the end)
2. use `regexp_split_to_table` along with `WITH ORDINALITY`  to **preserve the order**
3. `outer join` the location part to the original table (cast the `id`to `text`is it is `int`)
4. `string_agg` the location names to one string using the *ordinality* column and add the fixed slash prefix.

**Query**

```
with t2 as (
select * from  t,
regexp_split_to_table(substr(t.location,2), '/') WITH ORDINALITY x(part, rn)
),
t3 as (
select t2.*, t.name part_name from t2
left outer join t on t2.part = t.id::text)
select 
t3.id, t3.name, t3.location,
'/'||coalesce(string_agg(t3.part_name,'/' order by t3.rn),'') loc_name
from t3
group by 1,2,3
order by 1
```

gives result

```
id|name    |location|loc_name   |
--+--------+--------+-----------+
 1|Main    |/       |/          |
 2|Photos  |/1/3    |/Main/Media|
 3|Media   |/1      |/Main      |
 4|Charts  |/       |/          |
 5|Expenses|/4      |/Charts    |
```

Below the result of the subqueries to illustrated the steps

```
-- T2
id|name    |location|part|rn|
--+--------+--------+----+--+
 1|Main    |/       |    | 1|
 2|Photos  |/1/3    |1   | 1|
 2|Photos  |/1/3    |3   | 2|
 3|Media   |/1      |1   | 1|
 4|Charts  |/       |    | 1|
 5|Expenses|/4      |4   | 1|
 -- T3
 id|name    |location|part|rn|part_name|
--+--------+--------+----+--+---------+
 1|Main    |/       |    | 1|Main     |
 2|Photos  |/1/3    |1   | 1|Photos   |
 2|Photos  |/1/3    |3   | 2|Photos   |
 3|Media   |/1      |1   | 1|Media    |
 4|Charts  |/       |    | 1|Charts   |
 5|Expenses|/4      |4   | 1|Expenses |
```